# Smarty must have the variables in `backticks`

Tags: smarty, smarty2

I am trying to add 2 variable together inside of an assign. When reading the [Smarty Assign Documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.custom.functions.tpl#id2817973) it says:
**This complex example must have the variables in `backticks`**, what does this mean?

Comment: Soooo .. what's the question?

Comment: Sorry missed last bit off, edited question.

Comment: That's a backtick: `  so you will need to enclose your variables with this character, as it was said in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the following sign `

So you have

```
 assign variable = `value`
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official Smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl),

- Smarty will recognize assigned variables embedded in "double quotes" so long as the variable name contains only numbers, letters, under_scores and brackets[].
- With any other characters, for example a .period or $object->reference, then the variable must be surrounded by `backticks`.

In particular, if you are doing maths in, say, an assign, you need to use backticks for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

backticks are only necessary when inside quotes, and when you have variables with characters such as . ->  example:

```
{assign var="foo" value="myval is `$smarty.request.myval`"}
```